# How to create a password protected application in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I made fire fox add-on using java script. I want to give password protection to this add-on. Where can I store the user password permanently ? How can I do this?

Comment: Password will never be safe if you use pure JavaScript.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's no way to maintain state in that way beyond using cookies, which is probably not a viable option for a number of reasons. Could you be more specific about how/why you want to protect it?

Comment: @Derek: while your comment is completely true for JavaScript, absolutely safe may not be a strict requirement when developing add-on's that will run on the machine. After all, if you have access to the machine, you'll also be able to see all passwords that are stored in Firefox.

Comment: maybe you can use about:config, it will be stored in clear but you can access it anytime you want

Comment: You can consider using hashing instead of saving in plain text. You may also access OS's hashing APIs using ctypes.. Please, avoid plain-text passwords....

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to store on an external storage. Just like websites. You send the authentication data, server checks for user and returns true or false. There are a few problems with this. If you want to restrict parts of add-on for non-registred users, that's not possible. The whole code is available to the user and he can modify it.

If you create a website specific add/on search for a data (most likely in the cookies and preferences of the website) that is a secret, unpredictable, unique and uniform for a single user. You can hash that and use it as a password. Along with the username of that specific website. This way you can avoid registration.

Server communication trough HTTP is not too secure, but hey, most websites still use it.

If you don't have an external server available, you can use local storages like a SQLite, or i you have a single password you can use the [preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension) which are also available under about:config. But these are far from permanent. It's there until the user reinstall operating system, which unfortunately is quite common.

If you want closed source to hide storage mode, hash generating or something like that XP-COM components might help you but I don't recommend because it's really hard to maintain (all versions on all platforms).

Answer (score 0):

If the password is required to authenticate the user to a server then you should use [nsILoginManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/Using_nsILoginManager) to store it. The password will be stored encrypted on disk if the user defines a master password. If you want to protect the extension's user interface from the user then it doesn't matter where you store the password - this kind of protection works only against inexperienced users. E.g. you can use [Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences) to store it.